# Chrome radio buttons stopped working

Tags: html, google-chrome

Recently radio buttons on a web page that I maintain stopped working in webkit browsers Chrome and Safari.

They work just fine in Internet Explorer, Firefox for Window and Firefox for Mac.

By successively removing html from the page I have isolated the problem. It is caused by an adjacent div that has a height attribute. If I remove the height attribute on the adjacent div, the radio buttons work.

I tried to attach screen shots showing both cases. However only one screen shot seems to show when I save the edits. So it seems only one screen shot is allowed.

The visible screen shot shows after the problem is fixed by unchecking the height attribute of the "progress indicator" div.

[image: fixed condition with height attribute unchecked]

Comment: No way enough information to give you a reasonable response, webmasters focuses on webmaster issues not browsers, if you believe the page may be the problem then provide information about the page such as URL/HTML/JS the form etc.

Comment: I did not know which stack exchange section to post in. If you could suggest an alternative, that would be great.

Comment: I have more information. I have actually tracked down the exact cause of the issue, and I am thinking it is a Webkit bug. The radio buttons are in a div that is adjacent to another div. The other div has height. If I turn off the height attribute of the adjacent div, the radio buttons work. Would help if I could post screen shots, so will try that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution than working with the height. Instead add overflow:auto to the nearby div.